# Start a flask via systemd service

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, service, systemd

There is a systemd service file '/etc/systemd/system/flask-app.service:

```
[Unit]
Description="flask-app"
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root/FlaskApp/
Environment=/root/FlaskApp/flask-app/bin
ExecStart=/root/FlaskApp/flask-app/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After `sudo service flask-app start` nothing happens, and the `systemctl status` does not provide any specific information.
However, when i run *ExecStart* command (`/root/FlaskApp/flask-app/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0`) through the console, the service starts.

P.S. I have exported varable *FLASK_APP=flask-app.py*

P.P.S. My flask app created at venv.

Answer (score 1):

Well here it's my webflask.service, you need to declare env variable before you run or restart your service. **Example bellow**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Flask Web instance
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/opt/www
Environment="PATH=/opt/www/env/bin"
Environment="FLASK_SECRET_KEY=1234567"
Environment="FLASK_MYSQL_HOST=localhost"
Environment="FLASK_MYSQL_USER=base"
Environment="FLASK_MYSQL_PASSWORD=password"
Environment="FLASK_MYSQL_DB=base"
Environment="FLASK_APP=app.py"
Environment="FLASK_DEBUG=1"
Environment="TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD=1"
ExecStart=/opt/www/env/bin/flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And a flask server example, It's show you how to get the env variables:

```
from flask import Flask
import os 
flask_app = os.environ['FLASK_APP'] 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return f"{flask_app}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For my Pi3 I used next commands:

- sudo systemctl start myscript.service (can be started without .service)
- sudo systemctl status myscript.service (check what's going on)
- sudo systemctl enable myscript.service (if all is ok this allows autostart)

Here is https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md little bit more details.

Answer (score -1):

After you create the file, execute

```
sudo systemctl deamon-reload
```

Some corrections in your service file.

1. No need of WorkingDirectory=/root/FlaskApp/ if you are not going to use a  relative path for ExecStart= attribute.
2. Usage of Environment attribute is something different than what you are doing. [Check](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)