# Can't run selenium and flask in the same environment

Tags: selenium-webdriver, flask

I want to do web scrapping when the web endpoint is accessed by returning the page source of a website. the code is like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from flask import Flask
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from waitress import serve
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

app = Flask(__name__)

def driver_conf():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("enable-automation")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

@app.route('/')
def main():
  print("here main")
  return "here"

@app.route('/test')
def hello():
    print("open selenium")
    driver = driver_conf()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    element_text = driver.page_source
    print(element_text)
    return 'selenium has started'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("server started")
    serve(app,host = '0.0.0.0',port = 5000)
```

when the program is first run. flask can work well. when I access the route '/' flask returns "here"

when accessing route '/test'. the flask server also still responds well. but when selenium has finished running and prints the value of `driver.page_source` flask cannot respond at all

how to keep the flask server running when selenium has finished running?

this is the replit environment where I run the code
https://replit.com/@AllailQadrillah/Selenium-and-Flask

Comment: Do you mean run Flask as a service? Without knowing your OS, here I quote a Linux-based solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60401049/start-a-flask-via-systemd-service